# How to convert Php::DateInterval to seconds?

Tags: php

so, I substract two dates:

```
$d = $start->diff($end);
```

and now I want to get the date in seconds (not the `second` parameter). I know it can be done with a native Php function - but it only works above 1970. I know I have to somehow operate with `format()` method, but I dont get it...

Comment: Use format method.`$d->format('s');`. Im on mobile i cant cant test it but if it s dont work i can correct in few hour

Comment: php timestamps are signed ints. a 32bit timestamp will do 1902->2038, actually.

Comment: @BenjaminPoignant: it simply returns 's' :)

Comment: its not the "calculated" seconds. "0000-00-00 00:02:01" and "0000-00-00 00:00:00" returns 1, not 2*60+1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could access the [public properties of the `DateInterval` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) and do some math on it:

```
$seconds = $d->s + ($d->i * 60) + ($d->h * 3600) + ($d->d * 86400) + ($d->m * 2592000); // and so on
```

but once we get into the months there will be variance by +/- 2 days unless we stick to an arbitrary definition of a month as `2592000 secs` (30 days).

You can also use the difference of the two UNIX timestamps from the DateTime objects (but you will end up having problems with the dates being less than year of 1970):

```
$seconds = $end->getTimestamp() - $start->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: Will the +/- 2 be solved if you get the total number of days, instead of months?

Comment: thx, Ive just found it too here: https://www.liketly.com/forum/thread/12020/calculate-absolute-abnormal-in-php-dateinterval/ but are you sure a "manual" mathematic should play the role here?

Comment: @CEP No, because the days get rounded into the `m` property

Comment: @JohnSmith Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I meant, isnt it implemented by Php? The UNIX time shouldnt be converted to Ymd format either, by manually

Comment: @JohnSmith I still can't understand you. There is no "to seconds" functionality unless you utilize the UNIX timestamp conversion, but by definition of a UNIX timestamp, it won't work for dates less than the Unix epoch

Comment: You can use `$seconds = $d->s + ($d->i * 60) + ($d->h * 3600) + ($d->a * 86400);` a represent total of day

Answer (score 4):

How about using a class DateTime / DateTimeImmutable to create current DateTime instance, then add your DateInterval $d by using the add() method, and then using the getTimestamp() method.

```
(new \DateTimeImmutable())->add($d)->getTimestamp()
```

To get number of seconds from now, just subtract time().

```
(new \DateTimeImmutable())->add($d)->getTimestamp() - \time()
```

Answer (score 3):

The following seems to work, although I feel there should be a better way.

```
$dateIntrvl = $start->diff($end);

$days = $dateIntrvl->format('%a');
$hours = $dateIntrvl->format('%h');
$mins = $dateIntrvl->format('%i');
$secs = $dateIntrvl->format('%s');

$totalSeconds = ($days * 24 * 60 * 60) + ($hours * 60 * 60) + ($mins * 60) + $secs;
```

And yes, it seems to be working for dates earlier than `1970`.

Comment: thx, Ive just found it too here: https://www.liketly.com/forum/thread/12020/calculate-absolute-abnormal-in-php-dateinterval/ but are you sure a "manual" mathematic should play the role here?

Comment: Please elaborate _manual mathematic_. Do you mean to say that _a person_ should be doing this?

Comment: I meant, isnt it implemented by Php? The UNIX time shouldnt be converted to Ymd format either, by manually

Comment: If you mean you want to get the number of `seconds` between a point of time in the past, say `A`, and another point of time `B`, then it _has_ to be calculated. On the other hand, if you want to measure intervals of time between now and a point of time in the future, then you can probably use something like `microtime()` to do it.